# Is every topos a sheaf topos with values in a well-pointed one?

Tags: ct.category-theory, forcing, topos-theory

Here's a mix of heuristic and precise questions as I try to grapple with topos theory.

I try to think of topoi as two notions of "$1$" being glued at the hip. One is the "building block" $1$, generating the naturals, the ordinals, the cardinals... with all its usual arithmetic properties. This generates the set theory of a topos.

The other is the "all-encompassing" $1$, the highest truth value, the top element of a Heyting/Boolean algebra, whose subobjects form the algebra of truth values in the topos. This generates the logic of a topos.

Hence the set-theoretical properties (existence of an NNO, choice, CH, large cardinals...) happen "above $1$" and the logical properties (being Boolean, two-valued, well-pointed...) happen "below $1$" (whatever this means, this is just my heuristic).

Now Grothendieck topoi are defined as sheaf topoi with values in a certain well-pointed topos, namely $\textbf{Set}$. I can construct topoi that are not Grothendieck by taking a $\textbf{Set}$-like topos that is not $\textbf{Set}$, for example $\textbf{FinSet}$, and then considering sheaves valued in it. My first question is: are all topoi generated like this? **Is every topos equivalent to a topos of sheaves on a site** (its logic) **with values a well-pointed topos** (its set theory)**?**

Taking the functor $(-)^1$ of global elements seems to suggest the affirmative, as it is a logical functor to its image $\mathcal{I}$, which is well-pointed. Then the topos is, I assume, equivalent to the $\mathcal{I}$-valued sheaves on its Heyting algebra.

My second suspicion was that the logic and the set theory of a topos are independent of each other, but upon reviewing forcing, this doesn't seem to be the case. For example, following Mac Lane and Moerdijk, I can start with $\textbf{Set}$, value presheaves on a forcing poset $P$ in it ($\widehat{P}$), make it Boolean ($\widehat{P}_{\neg\neg}$) and mod out an ultrafilter ($\widehat{P}_{\neg\neg}/\mathcal{U}$). But then I've changed the set theory of a topos by only tinkering with its logic. In this light, forcing seems really unexpected and counterintuitive, by creating an interplay between what's happening "above $1$" and "below $1$". [I suppose this is exactly what the forcing theorem in material set theory says, though.] So my second question is: **To what extent does forcing measure the interdependence of the logic and the set theory of a topos? Is there a theorem describing this?**

It also surprises me that the two constructions $(-)^1$ and $/\mathcal{U}$ to collapse a topos to a well-pointed one don't coincide. For example, $\textbf{Set} \cong (\widehat{P}_{\neg\neg})^1$ and $\widehat{P}_{\neg\neg}/\mathcal{U}$ generally differ. Is there a deep reason for this? Is it perhaps because the ultrafilter-quotient construction is not as well-behaved and purely logical as I think?

Comment: The global element functor isn't a logical functor. I'm not sur what you mean in that part of your question or what you call $\mathcal{I}$.

Comment: It isn't? It's a right adjoint, preserves exponentials because $(Y^1)^{(X^1)} = (Y^X)^1$, $\textrm{Hom}(X^1, Y^1) = \textrm{Hom}((X^1)^1, (Y^1)^1)$ so well-pointedness goes through and therefore the SOC is automatically $\{0,1\}$ if it exists. I don't see why it wouldn't. So what goes wrong here? Also, $\mathcal{I}$ is the subcategory of objects of the form $X^1$ with morphisms of the form $f^1$.

Comment: Unless I'm missing some assumptions you are making, the globale element functor do not preserve exponential nor sub-object classifier and the image as you define has no reason to be a topos.

Comment: I see it now. With parameter $A$, we only get $\mathrm{Hom}(A, (Y^1)^{(X^1)}) = \mathrm{Hom}(A \times X^1, Y^1) = \mathrm{Hom}(A \times X^1, Y)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(A, (Y^X)^1) = \mathrm{Hom}(A \times X, Y)$, which only coincide if there's something well-pointed going on in the topos already to ensure morphisms coming out of $X^1$ are the same as ones coming out of $X$.

Comment: Ok, Either by $X^1$ you mean the exponential by $1$ in the topos, which is just the identity functor and then what you were saying is correct, but not very interesting because you are talking about the identity functor. Or you mean the globale section functors (Hom(1,X)) and what you are writting here do not make sense at all. $Hom(A \times X^1,Y^1) = Hom(A \times X^1,Y)$ make no sense as $A \times X^1$ is a set while $Y$ is an object of the topos. Even if the topos is well pointed, $Hom(1,\_)$ is in general not a logical functor.

Comment: To add to Simon's comments, here is a concrete example where taking global elements does not commute with exponentials. The global elements of the NNO $N$ of the effective topos are the plain old natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$. However, not every set-theoretic map $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is the induced map on global elements of a morphism $N \to N$ of the effective topos. Those induced maps are exactly the computable maps, but not every set-theoretic map is computable.

Comment: Hmm, I had a comment about Awodey's theorem about sheaf representations, but it seems to have vanished. Here's the paper https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4049(98)00076-0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution to your first question is given in "Sketches of an Elephant" by Johnstone, Example A4.4.2(d). If a topos $\mathcal{E}$ is the topos of sheaves on some internal site in a topos $\mathcal{S}$, then there is a natural geometric morphism $p : \mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{S}$. It turns out that there are toposes that do not admit geometric morphisms to Boolean toposes whatsoever. Two examples given by Johnstone are the effective topos and the topos of triples $(A,B,f)$ where $A$ is a set, $B$ is a finite set, and $f : A \to B$ is a function.

So these toposes cannot be written as a topos of sheaves over a Boolean topos (so also not over a well-pointed topos, because well-pointed toposes are Boolean).

Below is the argument that a geometric morphism $p : \mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{S}$ does not exist, for $\mathcal{E}$ the topos of triples $(A,B,f)$ as above and $\mathcal{S}$ a Boolean topos. I follow the Elephant, Example A4.5.24. Because subtoposes of Boolean toposes are again Boolean, we can assume that $p$ is surjective, so $p^*$ is faithful. Further, in $\mathcal{S}$ all objects are decidable, i.e. the diagonal embeddings $X \to X \times X$ have a complement. So the same holds for objects of the form $(A,B,f) = p^*(X)$. This condition implies that $f$ is injective, and as a result both $A$ and $B$ are finite. We conclude that there are only finitely many morphisms $p^*(X) \to p^*(Y)$, and because $p^*$ is faithful, it follows that there are only finitely many morphisms $X \to Y$, for $X,Y$ arbitrary. However, for $(A,1,f)$ with $A$ infinite, we get that there are infinitely many morphisms $1 \to p_*(A)$, so this gives a contradiction.